# Invoking a function with dependencies in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, configuration, routes, angular5

Using Angular 5 and UIRouter state routing. I'm using an additional custom route state property as per this interface.

```
interface AugmentedNg2RouteDefinition extends Ng2StateDeclaration {
    default?: string | ((...args: any[]) => string | Promise<string>);
}
```

When I define an abstract state, I can now add a `default` property to it as well, so when one would try to route to an abstract state, the default should redirect them to configured *default* child state.

As can be understood from the interface above, the `default` may be defined as any of the following:

```
// relative state name
default: '.child',
// absolute state name
default: 'parent.child',
// function with DI injectables
default: (auth: AuthService, stateService: StateService) => {
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return '.child';
    } else {
        return stateService.target('.login', { ... });
    }
}
// function with DI injectables returning a promise
default: (items: ItemsService) => {
    return items
        .getTotal()
        .then((count) => {
            return count > 7
                ? '.simple'
                : '.paged';
        });
}
```

To actually make the `default` work, I have to configure route transition service:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    UIRouterModule.forChild({  // or "forRoot"
      states: ...
      // THIS SHOULD PROCESS "default" PROPERTY ON ABSTRACT STATES
      config: (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, module: StatesModule) => {
        uiRouter.transitionService.onBefore(
          // ONLY RUN THIS ON ABSTRACTS WITH "default" SET
          {
            to: state => state.abstract === true && !!state.self.default
          },
          // PROCESS "default" VALUE
          transition => {
            let to: transition.to();
            if (angular.isFunction(to.default)) {
              // OK WE HAVE TO EXECUTE THE FUNCTION WITH INJECTABLES SOMEHOW
            } else {
              // this one's simple as "default" is a string
              if (to.default[0] === '.') {
                  to.default = to.name + to.default;
              }
              return transition.router.stateService.target(to.default);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    })
  ]
})
export class SomeFeatureModule { }
```

So the problem is invoking the `default` when it's a function that likely has some injectable services/values...

Configuration function's injector (`config: (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, module: StatesModule)`) can only be used to get service instances, but can't invoke functions with injectable parameters.

In AngularJS, this would be accomplished by `$injector.invoke(...)` which would call the function and inject its parameters.

## The main question

How should I handle `default` when it's defined as a function with injectables.

Comment: The question is about that `default` can be function at some point but in fact it isn't. What exactly does it look like? *config function's Injector can only get me instances of injectables which I can't really use here* - what does this mean? What are these instances and which ones are expected? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement are necessary here.

Comment: @estus: `default` can either be a string or a function that returns a string or a promise of string. The problem is that this function may require parameters which should be provided by the angular's DI container. That's why one would use `$injector.invoke` in AngularJS, but `.invoke` function is not available here in my Angular 5 code context. Do you understand the problem now?

Comment: There is no $injector.invoke in Angular, and DI-enabled functions should be defined as providers. It really matters what this function and these parameters (services?) are. Your comment doesn't explain this, *config function's Injector can only get me instances of injectables which I can't really use here*. Please, update the question with example that explains your case in detail, because the question cannot be addressed in general.

Comment: @estus I know there's no `$injector.invoke`. Why do you think I asked the question in the first place? I apparently haven't described my problem properly because you didn't understand what `default` state property does. So injected parameters (when `default` is a function with injectable parameters) may be anything that provides the information to decide which default child state should be selected. i.e. some authentication service... And my question is pretty much detailed enough for those that actually carefully read it. And it's not some basic problem. It's an advances problem.

Comment: @estus: I hope my severely edited question is now more clear and understandable. It may as well be, that I'm missing some knowledge so I can't make my question more clear as it is ATM. As it seems I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks. The thing that's important is what's ItemsService. Is it existing provider? Does it belong to a module? Is it allowed to be a singleton?

Comment: @estus. I suppose I'd add the service as a `provider`... The main thing is that module that configures my routing should be able to access it even though if it's just for the sake of routing configuration. If these services should be added to the module differently (or some other module) then please advise. In case of authentication service I would expect it to be singleton. In case of others they may or may not be. Provide example for each to cover both scenarios.

Comment: Looks ok. I have some ideas, I guess I'll come up with answer today.

Comment: @estus Thanks. I'll be more than glad if you do so as I'm trying to upgrade my existing app from AngularJS to Angular 5. Not as smooth as I though it would be. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct counterpart to AngularJS `$injector.invoke` in Angular, because injectable functions are expected to be `useFactory` providers that are defined on design time.

There is only one injector instance in AngularJS but a hierarchy of injectors in Angular, this also complicates things because a dependency is supposed to exist on injector that invokes a function.

The idiomatic way to handle this this is to define all functions that are expected to be invoked as providers. This means that a function is restricted to use instances from injector it was defined on (root or child module):

```
export function fooDefaultStateFactory(baz) {
  return () => baz.getStateName();
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    Baz,
    {
      provider: fooDefaultStateFactory,
      useFactory: fooDefaultStateFactory,
      deps: [Baz]
    }
  ],
  ...
})
...

// relative state name
default: '.child',
...
// function with DI injectables
default: fooDefaultStateFactory
```

Then factory functions can be retrieved as any other dependencies from injector and called:

```
  transition => {
    ...
    if (typeof to.default === 'string') {
      ...
    } else if (to.default) {
      const defaultState = injector.get(to.default);

      if (typeof defaultState === 'function') {
        // possibly returns a promise
        Promise.resolve(defaultState()).then(...)
      } else { ... }
    }
  }
```

A counterpart to `$injector.invoke` that works with any function should loosely resemble how constructor definition works in Angular 2/4 [`Class` helper](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.6/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts#L99-L142) (deprecated in Angular 5). The difference is that `Class` accepts constructor function that is annotated either with array or `parameters` static property, the annotations are expected to be an array of arrays because dependencies can involve decorators (`Inject`, `Optional`, etc).

Since decorators aren't applicable to a function that wasn't registered as provider, the array is expected to be plain, similarly to [AngularJS implicit annotations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) or `deps` in Angular `useFactory` provider:

```
function invoke(injector, fnOrArr) {
  if (Array.isArray(fnOrArr)) {
    const annotations = [...fnOrArr];
    const fn = annotations.pop();
    const deps = annotations.map(annotation => injector.get(annotation));
    return fn(...deps);
  } else {
    return fnOrArr();
  }
}
```

Can be bound to injector instance:

```
const injectorInvoke = invoke.bind(injector);
injectorInvoke([Foo, Bar, (foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => {...}]);
```

And the snippet that invokes a function is modified to:

```
  ...
  if (typeof defaultState === 'function' || Array.isArray(defaultState)) {
    // possibly returns a promise
    Promise.resolve(injectorInvoke(defaultState)).then(...)
  } else { ... }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can solve this with added part about resolving services.

```
// THE IMPORTANT PART
config: (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, module: StatesModule) => {
   uiRouter.transitionService.onBefore(
      // HookMatchCriteria
      {
         to: state => state.abstract === true && !!state.self.default
      },
      // TransitionHookFn
      transition => {
         let to: transition.to();
         if (typeof to.default === "string") {
            return transition.router.stateService.target(to.default);
         } else if (typeof to.default === "function") {
            let functionPromise = Promise.resolve(to.default(injector));
            return functionPromise.then((toDefault) => transition.router.stateService.target(toDefault));
         }
}
```

The first part of checking if the default is `string` is obvious. 
In the second `if` I check if the parameter is a function this automatically treats it as function in TypeScript so it can be called directly. On the result which can be a `Promise<string>` or `string` i then use the [Promise.resolve(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) method. This method returns a new `Promise<string>` for both inputs so then we can just chain it with the call to the stateService and it will return a `Promise<TargetState>` which is a valid return for the TransitionHookFn.

For resolving the services you can change you interface like this:

```
interface AugmentedNg2RouteDefinition extends Ng2StateDeclaration {
    default?: string | ((injector: Injector, ...args: any[]) => string | Promise<string>);
}
```

Then you also send the injector always when calling the function since you have it in the config method. If all the arguments are expected to be services then remove the `...args` an just send the injector.

Then the functions you gave as a sample would then look like this:

```
// relative state name
default: '.child',
// absolute state name
default: 'parent.child',
// function with DI injectables
default: (injector: Injector) => {
    let auth: AuthService = injector.get(AuthService);
    let stateService: StateService = injector.get(StateService);
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return '.child';
    } else {
        return stateService.target('.login', { ... });
    }
}
// function with DI injectables returning a promise
default: (injector: Injector) => {
    let items: ItemsService = injector.get(ItemsService);
    return items
        .getTotal()
        .then((count) => {
            return count > 7
                ? '.simple'
                : '.paged';
        });
```

Comment: You've used a simple `default` function. Paramless... That's not exactly the problem I'm trying to solve though. At least not the example I'm struggling with... Suppose that `default` function has a service parameter: `default: (myService: MyService) => { ... }`. How would you invoke the function now? You have to somehow get the injectable service instance. In AngularJS one would simply call `$injector.invoke()`, which would then inject parameters from DI container, but in Angular 5 we don't have the `invoke` function...

Comment: Ok I understand now did not read careful enough so I did not get this is the main issue. I would then change the function definition to take also the `Injector` as a parameter and then resolve the services in the function implementation from the injector directly. Will update the answer so you see what I mean.