# How to efficiently handle many resolves in Angular 5 routing?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Just starting a new project in Angular 5, coming from Angularjs, and I can't get my head around the resolve mechanism.

With Angular 1.x and ui-router, I could just really easily resolve data before my route was loaded this way :

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('myModule').config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('myState', {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'main@': {
          templateUrl: "/src/modules/template.part.html",
          controller: "MyController",
          resolve: {
            something: function(ServiceA) {
              return ServiceA.getSomething();
            },
            somethingElse: function (ServiceB, something) {
              return ServiceB.getSomethingElse(something);
            },
            otherThing: function (ServiceC) {
              return ServiceC.getOtherThing();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

And that was it, I could inject `something`and `somethingElse` in `MyController`.

Now with Angular 5, if I understood correctly, this is what I have to do for the same result :

```js
// skipping imports


@Injectable()
class ResolveA implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private myServicA: MyService) {}

  resolve()  {
    return this.myServiceA.getSomething()
  }
}


@Injectable()
class ResolveB implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private myServiceB: MyService) {}

  resolve()  {
    return this.myServiceB.getSomethingElse()
  }
}


@Injectable()
class ResolveC implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private myServiceC: MyService) {}

  resolve()  {
    return this.myServiceC.getOther()
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TestComponent,
    resolve: {
      dataA: ResolveA,
      dataB: ResolveB,
      dataC: ResolveC
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    MyService,
    ResolveA,
    ResolveB,
    ResolveC
  ]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }
```

I must have missed something because this really seems like a LOT of code for just 3 `return`'s. Is there no possibility at all to declare an inline function or something in the `resolve` part of my route ? Anywhere I look I can't find an answer to that question, I only see easy tutos and demos, but what about a big app with 5-10 resolves coming from different services ?

Or maybe I should do it in the `ngOnInit` function of my component ? But it doesn't feel right either...

This is more of a "good practice" question before I start working on a big project, I just want to be sure I'm doing things right. I've manage to remove some code by doing a `forkJoin` on all my observables inside a single resolver but again, this doesn't feel *quite* right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing resolvers one after the other in Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792626/executing-resolvers-one-after-the-other-in-angular-2)

Comment: You can compose resolvers and services any way you wish. If you need A, B and C be resolved together more than once, you can make them a single resolver.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, that means using a combination of await/forkJoin on my promises/observables to squeeze all of them into a single resolver ?

Comment: Yes. They are resolved in series in linked answer because they depend non each other, but you can do this in parallel, e.g. with Promise.all. The reason why resolvers are so verbose is that providers and routes should be defined in specific way to be supported by AOT, and also there is [no $injector.invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525807/3731501) for anonymous DI-enabled functions.